# Rails search model with country_select gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using `country_select` gem and managed to convert `country_code` to `country_name` in my `index.html.erb`.

Now, I have created a `Search` model, where I can use only `country_code` but `country_name`. Any idea how to convert that way users can select `country_name` but sending param remain `country_code`?

searches.controller.rb

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
 def new
    @search = Search.new
    @country = Property.uniq.pluck(:country_code)
 end
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @search, html: {class: "pure-form"} do |f| %>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Country" %>
    <%= f.select :country, options_for_select(@country), :include_blank => true%>
   </div>

  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Search", class: "btn" %></div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Well display a dropdown with name of the countries and their codes as its respective values.

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: No, not yet. Instead showing the countries, which are available, I show all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit the countries with only: option.

```
@limit_country = Property.pluck(:country).uniq

<%= form_for @search, html: {class: "pure-form"} do |f| %>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Country" %>
    <%= f.country_select :country, only: @limit_country, include_blank: true
   </div>

  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Search", class: "btn" %></div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: hello i want to know how to add class inside this country_select tag